# Pandas: create category column based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Which would be the most efficient way to create a category column based on other columns in the row, as quickly as possible?

input:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     0     0   -10     1
1     1   100     0    -1
2     0     0     0     1
3     0     0   -10     1
4     1   100     0    -1
```

output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4 new_col
0     0     0   -10     1       1
1     1   100     0    -1       2
2     0     0     0     1       3
3     0     0   -10     1       1
4     1   100     0    -1       2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest method is probably using numpy [`unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) (if all columns are numeric):

```
_, new_col = np.unique(df.to_numpy(), axis=0, return_inverse=True)
df['new_col'] = new_col
```

or as one-liner:

```
df['new_col'] = np.unique(df.to_numpy(), axis=0, return_inverse=True)[1]
```

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  new_col
0     0     0   -10     1        0
1     1   100     0    -1        2
2     0     0     0     1        1
3     0     0   -10     1        0
4     1   100     0    -1        2
```

---

This is about 10 times faster (for the sample data) than groupby on all columns and using the group number [`ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) as category code:

```
df['new_col'] = df.groupby(df.columns.to_list()).ngroup()
```

The advantage of this method is that it also works for mixed or non-numeric typed dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your logic is there but for example if you wanted to add the values of each column in a particular row together to make a new column you could do:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col1'] + row['col2'] + row['col3'] + row['col4'], axis=1)
```

which would output

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4 new_col
0     0     0   -10     1      -9
1     1   100     0    -1     100
2     0     0     0     1       1
3     0     0   -10     1      -9
4     1   100     0    -1     100
```

the axis=1 means you'd be creating a new column as opposed to axis=0 which would create a new row.

Comment: although this works by chance for the sample data it won't work in general as the same row sum can be formed by many different column values.